# A way to return control to Windows when window is not the focus OpenGL - C++

Tags: c++, opengl, focus

I was wondering if there was an OpenGL command to return control to Windows when the window the rendering is happening in is no longer the focus. As it stands, the mouse is constantly moved to the center of the screen even when it is not the focus.

Any way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to answer your question. OpenGL doesn't provide any mouse capture facilities on its own: it's purely a graphics API. What are you using to gain 'control' of the mouse? Can you post a short section of code to show us what your code is doing?

Comment: I think you're using some framework, like SDL, GLFW or the like. It's this framework to blame, not OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL is a rendering API; it does not have commands that deal with the underlying windowing system. WGL, GLX, and Apples AGL do that sort of thing. And even those APIs don't deal with mouse movement.

If the mouse is being forced to the center of the screen by your application, then it is probably due to some other code that you are using. Many of the common tools for creating OpenGL windows (FreeGLUT, GLFW, Qt, wxWidgets, etc) have commands for capturing the mouse and affecting its position. You will need to check your code and the documentation of whatever software you're using to interface with your window to see where the problem lies.

Comment: GLX is just responsible for the OpenGL commands being passed to the X server. The problem the OP has would fall into normal X operation, and maybe EMWH.

Answer (score 0):

For windows, make sure you're setting mouse position if windows is active.

```
if(getactivewindow() == this->hwnd)
    setmousepos()
```

This is probably the issue.